# Detecting IP and Selecting state

Tags: javascript, php

Can anybody tell me how the state can be selected in the drop-down by recognizing automatically the IP address?
I haven't tried anything so if  you have any formula please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try http://ipinfo.io/

PHP:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
echo $details->city; // -> "Mountain View"
```

or in javascript:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.city);
}, "jsonp");
```